# How to get near optimal parallel efficiency for this simple Julia code?

Tags: multithreading, julia, vectorization

I have the following simple code:

```
function hamming4(bits1::Integer, bits2::Integer)
    return count_ones(bits1 ⊻ bits2)
end

function random_strings2(n, N)
    mask = UInt128(1) << n - 1
    return [rand(UInt128) & mask for i in 1:N]
end




function find_min(strings, n, N)
    minsofar = fill(n, Threads.nthreads())
    # minsofar = n
    Threads.@threads for i in 1:N 
    # for i in 1:N
        for j in i+1:N
            dist = hamming4(strings[i], strings[j])
            if dist < minsofar[Threads.threadid()]
                    minsofar[Threads.threadid()] = dist

            end
        end
    end
    return minimum(minsofar)
    #return minsofar
end


function ave_min(n, N)
    ITER = 10
    strings = random_strings2(n, N)
    new_min = find_min(strings, n, N)
    avesofar = new_min
    # print("New min ", new_min, ". New ave ", avesofar, "\n")
    total = avesofar
    for i in 1:ITER-1
        strings = random_strings2(n, N)
        new_min = find_min(strings, n, N)
        avesofar = avesofar*(i/(i+1)) + new_min/(i+1)
        print("Iteration ", i, ". New min ", new_min, ". New ave ", round(avesofar; digits=2), "\n")
    end
    return avesofar
end

N = 2^16
n = 99

print("Overall average ", ave_min(n, N), "\n")
```

When I run it on an AMD 8350 in linux the CPU usage is around 430% (instead of close to 800%).

> Is it possible to make the parallelisation work more efficiently?

Also, I noticed a new very impressive looking package called [LoopVectorization.jl](https://github.com/chriselrod/LoopVectorization.jl). As I am computing [the Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) in what looks like a vectorizable way, is it possible to speed up the code this way too?

> Can the code be vectorized using LoopVectorization.jl?

(I am completely new to Julia)

Answer (score 4):

The parallelization of your code seems to be correct.

Most likely you are running it in Atom or other IDE. Atom by default is using only half o cores (more exactly using only physical not logical cores).

Eg.g  running in Atom on my machine:

```
julia> Threads.nthreads()
4
```

What you need to do is to explicitly set `JULIA_NUM_THREADS`

Windows command line (still assuming 8 logical cores)

```
set JULIA_NUM_THREADS=8
```

Linux command line

```
export JULIA_NUM_THREADS=8
```

After doing that your code takes 100% on all my cores.

#### EDIT

After discussion - you can get the time down to around 20% of a single threaded time by using `Distributed` instead of `Threads` since this avoids memory sharing:

The code will look more or less like this:

```
using Distributed
addprocs(8)

@everywhere function hamming4(bits1::Integer, bits2::Integer)
    return count_ones(bits1 ⊻ bits2)
end

function random_strings2(n, N)
    mask = UInt128(1) << n - 1
    return [rand(UInt128) & mask for i in 1:N]
end

function find_min(strings, n, N)
    return @distributed (min) for i in 1:N-1
        minimum(hamming4(strings[i], strings[j]) for j in i+1:N)
    end
end

### ... the rest of code remains unchanged
```

Comment: I in fact do that already. Do you get all 8 cores used when you test it? What speed up are you getting over using 1 core? Someone else tested it online and found the equivalent of 3 cores out of 6 being used fully.  (My IDE is Virtual Studio code but I haven't worked out how to make it use more than one core so I just run it from the command line.)

Comment: On my laptop I get 10.3s for `ave_min(n, N)` with 100% constant CPU load time (Windows 10). All looks legit to me. Typical problems include false sharing or garbage collection but all looks good for me. What performance you would get on Linux?

Comment: For 8 threads: 34 seconds; 4 threads, 54 seconds; 1 thread 127 seconds.   What do you  get with a different number of threads?

Comment: 1-32s, 2-24s, 4-14s, 8-10s. Since Intel CPU can  burst when to fully loaded this looks fine to me. Try using Linux on AWS and let know what are the loads and times.

Comment: So it seems that 8 threads is only 3.2x times faster than 1 for you. That is roughly the problem I was concerned about.

Comment: Hyperthreading usually adds something like +25%-40% to the performane because double logical cores  operate on a single physical core. And when only a single core is used Intel Turbo Boost kicks-in overclocking. Especially this is true for short time workloads. Additionally, you have lots of data and hence loads of memory sharing between threads. Try using `Distributed.@distributed` loop (combined with `addprocs(8)`) this will avoid memory sharing between threads and could be better sometimes.

Comment: OK I did it for you but test for bugs ;-)